# How to calculate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^n - 2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

By the test of reason, this series converges. 
The problem is figuring out which technique to use to calculate your sum.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I doubt this series has a closed form.

Comment: Good question. I do not know if there is a way. I had not thought of that.

Comment: The test of reason is my favorite convergence test.

Comment: @AntonioVargas, I'm guessing that the OP means "ratio test." The word "rational" has two very different meanings and this probably led to a poor translation.

Comment: Wolfram alpha tells that the limit of the sum is $≈1,27498$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B3%5En-2%5En%7D%7D

Answer (score 5):

You can express the sum in terms of the $q$-digamma function $\psi_q(z)$.  This isn't a profound simplification, however, because $\psi_q(z)$ is defined as a sum of a similar form:
$$
\psi_q(z) = \frac{\partial \log \Gamma_q(z)}{\partial z} = -\log(1-q) + \log(q) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{q^{n+z}}{1-q^{n+z}}.
$$
But, for what it's worth,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n-2^n} = \frac{\log3-\psi_{2/3}(\log_{3/2}3)}{\log(3/2)}.
$$

Comment: Who is $\Gamma_q(z)$?

Comment: $\Gamma_q(z)$ is the $q$-gamma function.  There are many functions that have "$q$-analogs," and I included the reference to $\Gamma_q(z)$ in order to emphasize that the definition of $\psi_q(z)$ isn't some strange, arbitrary thing, but rather the derivative of $\log \Gamma_q(z)$, in analogy to the definition of the standard digamma function.